# Secure (https) import of jquery mobile js and css is failing when using relative paths

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using relative path to include jquery mobile. But when loading thru a secure(https) link, the imports are failing. I do the following :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

jquery from googleapis goes thru fine. But I get the the following error for mobile .js and .css imports above.

Failed to load resource https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile.min.css

Failed to load resource https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile.js

Sorry if this seems like a pedestrian question, I am new to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you click on both of the failed resource links, you'll understand why.

code.jquery.com doesn't have a valid SSL certificate.

As Quinn says, you should copy those JS files to your server and serve them yourself, or set up a proxy page in PHP or another scripting language that will fetch the files over HTTP and serve them up from your server.

Comment: keep a copy of your scripts locally for use over ssl

Comment: Thank very much for your quick responses !! So essentially there is no way to load them from a googleapis equivalent site. I would rather have these files served/cached/etc publicly across geographic sites and not burden the local server with one more dependency. (also are there any other efficiency gains, if a the scripts are already cached for the browser/device thru prior pages ?)

Comment: You should find a publicly available HTTPS site that serves up your `jquery.mobile` CSS and JS files. Yes, you'll have performance gains if the JS and CSS are cached from other pages/sites if the server sets the expiry of these files far into the future.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will look out for googleapis or another site to serve this in the future. For now will serve these files thru my server.

Comment: The Microsoft Ajax Content Delivery Network serves jQuery Mobile over SSL - [see here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/CDN.ashx#jQuery_Mobile_Releases_on_the_CDN_4).